# Base System Devices

Tags: drivers

I have an Acer 4730Z. I have yellow error marks for my base system device. First I don't know what a base system devices. Second, I don't know where to go to find the drivers.I also just upgraded from Windows Vista to Windows 7
Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

It's all right here, including Win7: http://gd.panam.acer.com/home/

Just download everything listed for Travelmate 4730GZ for your Windows (x32 or x64 is very important), and get the latest BIOS as well. Install everything and all driver warnings should go away. Note: The specific "Base System" driver you're missing is the [Jmicron Card Reader Driver (JMB385)](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/CardReader/CardReader_Jmicron_1.00.32.01_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=633917962532761634&Step1=Notebook&Step2=TravelMate&Step3=TravelMate%204730ZG&OS=721&LC=en&BC=Acer&SC=PA_7), but you'd be well off installing the latest of everything.