# Is there a utility or a method to easily determine what an "unknown device" is in Device Manager?

Tags: windows, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [identify components at laptops](https://superuser.com/questions/71132/identify-components-at-laptops)

Is there a utility or a method to easily determine what an "unknown device" is in Device Manager?

I recently reinstalled Windows on a laptop and I have several "Base System Device" items listed in Device Manager.  In the past, I have downloaded drivers from the manufacturer until I find the one that works. I am just curious if there is a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [identify components at laptops](http://superuser.com/questions/71132/identify-components-at-laptops) also check [Base System Devices](http://superuser.com/questions/225070/base-system-devices), and/or [Hardware ID on Device Manager](http://superuser.com/questions/40208/hardware-id-on-device-manager), and/or [Get compnent detail - what tool to use](http://superuser.com/questions/263393/get-compnent-detail-what-tool-to-use)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, the other questions are not specific to identifying "Unknown Devices"

Answer (score 5):

try one of these

http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html

http://www.halfdone.com/

Comment: +1 unknown device identifier has helped me several times

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the tools mentioned, many laptop vendors have a tool designed to get the latest drivers.  Lenovo has one that works well.  Check with the laptop maker.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the device and vendor IDs in the properties of the device. Each of them should be a 4 digit number. Than you can just use google or any device ID database on the internet. This way you won't need to install additional software.
[This](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/) site may help you finding the IDs.

Comment: They did say "easily" determine. Good advice none the less.