# Get more information about uninstalled devices

Tags: windows, drivers

How to find more information about uninstalled devices?

I have a HP Envy 17 and HP only support windows 8 drivers, but I want to run windows 7

Have found almost all drivers.. But in some cases I can't find any information about the devices in the device manager

How is it possible to find drivers to unknown devices or devices which doesn't provide any details about it!?

[image]

Comment: So the device manager just lists some devices as unknown or with a question mark? Are you still running Win8 or already switched to Win7?

Comment: have added a print screen

Comment: check out these Q&As http://superuser.com/questions/291607/is-there-a-utility-or-a-method-to-easily-determine-what-an-unknown-device-is-i?rq=1 and following the links, to see some methods for discovering based on IDs.

Comment: On above screen hit drop down and select **hardware Ids**.  The first part VEN is the vendor ID and DEV is the DEVICE ID.  Type them in here http://www.pcidatabase.com/  and the results should tell you what you need to know.  Also slimdrivers maybe able to find,download, and install them for you.  Make sure you download from them and not the cnet download link.